# How to enable file-upload in phonegap inappbrowser?

Tags: android, cordova, file-upload, inappbrowser

I have following problem: I develope an app with PhoneGap. To display an external page I use the inappbrowser. The problem is, that on one page the user is able to upload some images, but the `<input type="file">` tag in inappbrowser does not work. I have full control over the external page. So do you have some ideas how to manage this problem?

Sincerely

Comment: if you have full control over the external page then don't load it on inAppBrowser, get the html with ajax and load it on the regular cordova webview. Anyways, the input type file is broken on android 4.4, so it's better to avoid using it and use a file chooser plugin and the file transfer API

Comment: Here is the Android bug: http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=62220

Comment: Thank you for your answers. I don't understand why google did such a mistake. My workaround for this prolem is rather simple. When I have a page with a file-input field I open it in an iFrame. In this iFrame everything works corrently. Strange...

Comment: Here's an easy fix for this scenario: http://stackoverflow.com/a/42375766/1457709