# cordova inappbrowser and input file

Tags: android, cordova, file-upload

I have a iOS and Android application, and I load a external website inside my app (this external website is mine too). 
My problem is that this website has a file upload feature and this feature does not work on Android (it works on iOS).
I saw that this behavior is normal on Android, but is there any way to make it work or it's definitely not an option ? 
Thank you

**EDIT 1**

I tried to create a new app with a simple page like this (hosted on AWS) :

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Upload Test !</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div>Upload Test</div>
    <div>
        <input type="file" id="imgFile" name="files[]" accept="image/x-png, image/gif, image/jpeg">
    </div>      
</body>
```

and I added this script in my generated index.html in my Cordova project.

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        document.addEventListener("deviceready", function(event) {
            console.log('TEST CONSOLE LOG !');
            var url = 'https://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/***/file-upload.html';
            ref = window.open(url, "_blank", "location=no,toolbar=no,zoom=no,hidden=yes");

            ref.addEventListener('loadstop', function () {
              ref.show();
            });
            ref.addEventListener('loaderror', function () {
              ref.close();
              ref = undefined;
            });
        }, false);
    </script>
```

It doesn't work on my nexus 5 (android M).

Comment: Its very difficult to help out unless someone sees what code you have tried so far.

Comment: I have a simple <input file (the default one) that is loaded from a remote webpage inside my inappbrowser. It doesn't open the file explorer on Android (it does on iOS). I tried inside chrome on my android device and it works, It's really the inappbrowser problem.
Here is the html tag : <input type="file" id="imgFile" name="files[]" accept="image/x-png, image/gif, image/jpeg">

Comment: input type file seems to have certain problem with android as far as I know. try to use image picker plugin if feasible

Comment: yes, input file has issue in some android versions.but works in latest ones L and M. The workaround for older device is wrap it in iFrame.

Comment: I edited my post to include a new test with a fresh cordova app. It does not work on my nexus 5 with Android M. is it normal ?

Answer (score 0):

There's an issue with both Android and iOS that prevents file uploads when clicking on a file input tag like this within the inappbrowser:

```
<input type="file">
```

There's a couple of fixes for both which I've consolidated into a single location to make it easy for anyone else facing this issue.  You should be able to modify your config.xml file to use it by including this:

```
<plugin spec="https://github.com/jverlee/cordova-plugin-inappbrowser-camera.git" version="1.1.0" source="git" />
```

Instead of the default inappbrowser plugin.

More details can be found here:
https://github.com/jverlee/cordova-plugin-inappbrowser-camera

Comment: Sorry, but your installation guide cannot work in cordova. I have provided the improvement which can work in my machine. See this: https://github.com/jverlee/cordova-plugin-inappbrowser-camera/issues/9

Answer (score 0):

`@Verl`'s code is pretty good! However, it cannot be installed through his installation guide... So here is mine:

```
cordova plugin remove cordova-plugin-inappbrowser-camera
cordova plugin add https://github.com/jverlee/cordova-plugin-inappbrowser-camera.git
```

By the way, if I follow his guide, I only gets: 
*Error: Cannot read property 'variables' of undefined*