# inAppBrowser input type=file option to take a photo missing goes straight to file manager

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins, inappbrowser

I have an Ionic Cordova App and i'm using an inAppBrowser to load my web app. I encountered this scenario where in after clicking the upload button (input type=file), it doesn't ask if i want to take a photo, it just goes straight to the file manager.

Solutions that I Tried :

1. tried this [cordova inappbrowser and input file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37642772/cordova-inappbrowser-and-input-file/42588948#42588948) however i cannot install it properly
2. I made sure all permissions are enable (which i can verify via settings-> app > permissions

I'm testing on :

```
cli packages:

@ionic/cli-plugin-cordova       : 1.5.0 
@ionic/cli-plugin-ionic-angular : 1.4.0 
@ionic/cli-utils                : 1.6.0 
ionic (Ionic CLI)               : 3.6.0
```

global packages:

```
Cordova CLI : 7.0.1
```

local packages:

```
@ionic/app-scripts : 2.0.2
Cordova Platforms  : android 6.2.3 ios 4.4.0
Ionic Framework    : ionic-angular 3.5.3
```

System:

```
Node       : v7.4.0
OS         : macOS Sierra
Xcode      : Xcode 8.3.3 Build version 8E3004b 
ios-deploy : 1.9.1 
npm        : 4.0.5
```

Below is my Expectations (Which is actually working when on a normal browser but not inside the inAppBrowser) :

[image]

Comment: I am testing an an emulator google pixel android 7.1.1 and real device 5.1

Comment: can you paste the html code for the input?

Comment: <input type="file" capture="camera" accept="image/*" name="myFile"/> something like this